# Filter functionality with time DIFFERENCES

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to run a filter function that will catch and display any unusual entries from a dataset. The speadsheet is receiving this data from a separate spreadsheet that is editable by multiple users; this results spreadsheet is editable only by me. I'm running into two problems.

[image]

**Problem 1:** I want the filter function capture *any* of three conditions. For two conditions (departure time = absent or no arrival time provided), the formula works perfectly as seen here:

```
=sort((filter({A4:F},(E4:E="absent")+ISBLANK(F4:F))),5,FALSE)
```

The problematic part of the filter deals with times. We have a column for time sent (Col. E) and another for time arrived (Col. F).

**Desired solution:** I want to capture any row where the difference between the two times is greater than four minutes.

**Attempted solution:** I wanted to do this with a simple subtraction (F$4-E$4), but I couldn't figure out how to get that to work in the filter formula, though it's what I'd prefer. So, I added a column that subtracted Col. E from Col. F (Col. G), and formatted it to Time Duration. This worked -- partially (that's problem #2). Then, I tried to set up the filter function (for simplicity, I broke it out individually from the other two conditions). After several formula parse errors, I came up with:

```
=sort((filter({A4:F},G4:G>"0:04:00")),5,FALSE)
```

This doesn't produce a parse error, but it doesn't produce any results, either, even though it should. If it ran perfectly, and setting aside blank cells, it should be picking up three: Crabbe, Finnigan, & Thomas. Do I have the wrong term in the "greater than" portion, or is it something else?

**Problem 2 (a corollary of problem 1):**

Users can enter times on their spreadsheet with checkboxes that auto-insert a timestamp, or type the time themselves (if a time is being entered after the fact). The auto-entered values include the (current) date. The manually-entered ones don't. When a script exports the results into this spreadsheet and I run the duration calculation in Col. G, it thinks all of the self-entered dates are from 12/30/1899, and produces huge differences that the filter function would erroneously flag (if I can ever get it to work). Can I iron this out on my end, or do I have to tell the users that they just can't enter times manually at all?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

One way if you don't go from one day to another is to substract only the "decimals" of the date. That is what is less than one day. For example: =A1-INT(A1)

Then, if you substract both differences (start and end), you end up with a fraction that multiplied by 24 hours and 60 minutes, returns the value in minutes:

```
=((B11-INT(B11))-(A1-INT(A1)))*24*60
```

If you want it to compare with 4 minutes:

```
=(((B11-INT(B11))-(A1-INT(A1)))*1000*60)>4
```

And, finally, to pass it as an argument, you can use it inside MAP:

```
=MAP(E2:E,F2:F, LAMBDA(s,e,(((e-INT(e))-(s-INT(s)))*24*60)>4))
```

You can just insert it inside your FILTER as a condition, no need of an auxiliary column